# Saving image from numpy array gives errors

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

this function is to show image of adversarial and its probability, I only want to download the image.

```
def visualize(x, x_adv, x_grad, epsilon, clean_pred, adv_pred, clean_prob, adv_prob):
    
    x = x.squeeze(0)     #remove batch dimension # B X C H X W ==> C X H X W
    x = x.mul(torch.FloatTensor(std).view(3,1,1)).add(torch.FloatTensor(mean).view(3,1,1)).numpy()#reverse of normalization op- "unnormalize"
    x = np.transpose( x , (1,2,0))   # C X H X W  ==>   H X W X C
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 1)
    
    x_adv = x_adv.squeeze(0)
    x_adv = x_adv.mul(torch.FloatTensor(std).view(3,1,1)).add(torch.FloatTensor(mean).view(3,1,1)).numpy()#reverse of normalization op
    x_adv = np.transpose( x_adv , (1,2,0))   # C X H X W  ==>   H X W X C
    x_adv = np.clip(x_adv, 0, 1)
    
    x_grad = x_grad.squeeze(0).numpy()
    x_grad = np.transpose(x_grad, (1,2,0))
    x_grad = np.clip(x_grad, 0, 1)
    
    figure, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(80,80))
    ax[0].imshow(x_adv)

    im = Image.fromarray(x_adv)
    im.save("car.jpeg")
    files.download('car.jpeg')
    plt.show()
```

I am getting this error here

TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <f4

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
im = Image.fromarray(x_adv)
```

to this:

```
im = Image.fromarray((x_adv * 255).astype(np.uint8))
```